# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two points in a metric space, such that $d(x, y) < 1/n$ for any natural $n$. Show that $x = y$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have the following outline for my proof.

Suppose $x$ is not equal to $y$. Then,
$d(x,y)=a <1/n, $ $\forall n \in N$, where $a$ is a positive real.
Now, $\ y \in B_{1/n_{1}}(x)$ for some $\ n_{1} \in N$
For $n_{2}<n_{1}$, $y\in B_{1/n_{2}}(x)$. 
Similarly for $n_{3}<n_{2}<n_{1}$, $y\in B_{1/n_{3}}(x)$ and so on.

If $x$ is not equal to $y$, then clearly $\quad \exists r=a/2$ such that $y\notin B_{1/r}(x)$.

Claim: It is possible to find an $n_{0}\in N$ such that $1/n_{0}<1/r$.

So, $y\notin B_{1/n_{0}}(x)$ which is a contradiction.

So, $x=y$.

My question is how to substantiate the claim that "It is possible to find an $n_{0}$ such that $1/n_{0}<1/r$".

Also, is the approach correct?

Comment: The Archimedean axiom says that for any real number $r$, there's an integer $n_0$ with $n_0 > r$. Take 1 over both sides to get the statement you needed.

Comment: @John Is the overall approach correct?

Comment: It's correct, but convoluted. See @Brian's answer below.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. But my approach is basically the same as Brian's, isn't it? It's just that I took $a/2$ in place of $a$

Comment: Right...but it's a good chance for you to try to write out the leanest and simplest possible proof, which is a good skill. :)

Comment: I completely agree

Answer (score 2):

You’re working much too hard. Once you assume that $x\ne y$ and let $a=d(x,y)>0$, you need only show that there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac1n\le a$. This follows directly from the [Archimedean property](http://planetmath.org/archimedeanproperty) of $\Bbb R$, since $\frac1n\le a$ iff $n\ge\frac1a$.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. But my approach is basically the same as yours, isn't it? It's just that I took $a/2$ in place of $a$

Comment: @Martin: Once you get to that point, yes. However, you also have a good deal of irrelevant material: you only ever use the first two sentences of the first paragraph of your outline. The discussion of $n_1,n_2$, and $n_3$ goes nowhere and isn’t used.

Comment: Yeah right. I was basically trying to develop the idea. I am new at analysis

Comment: @Martin: No problem. By the way, it isn’t necessarily true that there is an $n_1$ with $y\in B_{1/n_1}(x)$; what if $a\ge 1$?

Comment: Absolutely, I understand that.

Comment: @Martin: Then you’re probably in fairly good shape and mostly need practice organizing and writing — not an uncommon situation!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Metric spaces are Hausdorff, and $\{B(x,\frac1n)\mid x\in X,n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a basis for the metric topology.